# How to retrieve information from a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a django template that calls a python methods but I can't seem to find a way for the python method to retrieve information from the template such as user input. Could anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Learn [The Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#module-django.forms)

Comment: User input, just with HTTP requests... right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're under a misconception (A reasonably common one) that because you can use django variables in the html template, the template can "send" information back to django/the database.

Instead, try to get into the habit of thinking in terms of request/response. The user requests a web page, the django server builds up the response using content from the database and an html template (via the template language) and serves it to the user. If the response page has a form in it, that's not the "template" sending information back to the Django server, that's the response web page providing the user will tools to make ANOTHER request (this time a `POST` request).

The template is merely a generic container that you fill up with your dynamic content to build up the entire HTTP response.